# Relacionamento entre classes Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Sou iniciante com Asp.net, estou fazendo um site com agendamento de horários para uma barbearia, utilizando o Identity do Asp.Net para autenticação e autorização dos usuários. No entanto, estou em dúvida se será necessário criar uma classe usuários para listar as informações na agenda, como usuário, o horário e o serviço agendado, ou posso utilizar as informações dos usuários extraindo do Identity? Se sim, como faço o relacionamento entre as classes, uma vez que o Identity ficará em um contexto separado. Aproveitando, o contexto deve mesmo ficar separado?

Comment: Bom pessoal, recebi uma ajuda de uma amigo que me passou o seguinte: devo usar o mesmo contexto, porém criei uma classe usuário herdada de IdentityUser e assim utilizei os atributos da classe conforme minha necessidade.